# How do I serialize checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra

I have a table with checkboxes with doesn't contain a form for some reason. I want to get all checked checkboxes and send them to the server by appending to the main form serialized data. Here is how I'm doing this:

```
function f1(){
  var data = '';
  $(".chk").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      data += "" // what should be here?
    }
  });

 return data;
}
```

A checkbox looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="items[]" value="123">
```

where value is unique id.

I guess `data +=` should be like `items[0]=1&item[1]=13&item[2]=445`

So how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but I was under the impression it was able to build arrays without having to specify indices, i.e. `items[]=1&items[]=13&items[]=445` will give the results you're expecting.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the clientside code is JavaScript, not PHP. The serverside is Ruby/Sinatra. It has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function f1(){
  var data = '';
  var i = 0;
  $(".chk").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      if(i==0){
       data+="?items["+i+"]="+$(this).val();
      }else{          
       data+="&items["+i+"]="+$(this).val();
      }
    }
i++;
  });

 return data;
}
```